# issue in 'onCreate' method on android

Tags: java, android, oncreate

Before everything, I apologize, my question might seems silly.
I'm a beginer with the making of android software. I'm seeking help because i have got no idea where the problem comes from.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("debug", "I'm not going to appear on the LogCat ;_;");
        SomeStaticClass.something();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    //called from a button in activity_main.xml
    public void hello (View view) {
        Log.d("debug", "but for some reasons I will");
    }
}
```

as you can see the first  `Log.d`  in the onCreate function is never called. Or it never appear in the LogCat I don't now. Here is my probleme, because of this, I don't know if `SomeStaticClass.something()` is ever called ! Does anyone now why or has an idea ? Thank you.

(edit)
thank you in the comment :-). yes the breakpoint was a great idea ( I really feel ashamed that i didn't figured that one by myself ... ). So yes, the function is called, yet, Log.d still (4 times on 5) not show anything but only in the  `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` .
It is not much of a problem anymore now that I know it works, i'll marked it as solved. Yet, just by curiosity, does anyone knows why log.d doesn't write anything ?

Comment: What is the level on your LogCat set at? It could be set to hide debug messages. Try to change the level or use `Log.e()` for errors. Also, you can use breakpoints to see what is happening in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Logcat is set to Verbose log level by default. This means that you can either use Log.v instead of Log.d or switch to Debug log level in Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I have a always working answer. I just need to replace  `Log.d("what", "ever");`  by  `System.out.println("whatever");` . The reason is still unclear but it doesn't matter anymore. I'm terribly sorry for taking your time and bothering you all. Thank you all for the help.